# Импорт переменной. Как получить доступ к переменной из другого файла?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я пытаюсь сделать переменную глобальной и получить доступ к ней с другого файла, но у меня ничего не получается.

**HTML**:

```
<body>
    <button id="btn">Кнопка</button>
    <script src="/main.js"></script>
    <script src="/additional.js"></script>
</body>
```

**main.js**:

```
import { globalVar } from "./additional.js";
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  alert(globalVar.value);
});
```

**additional.js**:

```
export var globalVar = {
  value: "Hello world!"
};
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы использовать `import` и `export` вы должны обращаться к файлу как к модулю, добавив `type="module"`.
И вам не нужно подключать `additional.js`, потому что переменная импортирована уже в `main.js`.

### Пример:

```
<body>
    <button id="btn">Кнопка</button>
    <script src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

---

Печально, что мы не можем показывать работу модулей в SO песочнице, [полноценный пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/jj64k3op8y) можете посмотреть по ссылке.

---

И да переменная `globalVar` не является глобальной, это локальная переменная, которая импортирована из другого файла. Любые другие модули могут также импортировать данную переменную или любые другие переменные, но они *не глобальные*.